# How to automate a mongo db command?

Tags: mongodb, bash, terminal, automation, zsh

Since the `sudo mongod` command did not work for my macOS version *(/ data/db path was not found)*, I changed the path to `/System/Volumes/Data/data/db`.

To start mongo I always have to enter `sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db` so that the new path is recognized.

Is there a way to design this process so that I only have to enter `sudo mongod` again?

I'm using the following macOS version: **Catalina 10.15.3** with zsh

Comment: With [brew](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/9630872) or [launchctl](http://juanroy.es/how-to-run-mongodb-as-a-service-on-mac-osx/)

Comment: Installed with brew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for config file of MongoDB and check the content of:

```
storage:
   dbPath: <string>
```

And `dbPath` must point to the `/System/Volumes/Data/data/db`

The usual location of config file is `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Ok sounds good, but I can't find the config file. What is the exact name of the file?

Comment: @Codehan25, search for `mongod.conf`